# Satis - How to only include the "dist" downloads

Tags: composer-php, packagist, satis

We've started to use Satis for a private composer repository.

All is going well - except something which we cannot figure out.

--

When we run the satis build - it generates the json and the zips to download.

Our config resembles something like

```
{
    "name": "Premium Repositories",
    "homepage": "https://some-website.com",
    "require-all": false,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:our-repo.git"
        }
    ],
    "archive": {
        "directory": "dist"
    }
}
```

The json it then generates contains something like

```
"some/package": {
    "dev-master": {
        "name": "some/package",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "version_normalized": "9999999-dev",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:selesti/some-package.git",
            "reference": "db0abb6a6983738d768b64684f82d178059b85b4"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://some-domain/dist/some/package/some-package-dev-master-ec67bc.zip",
            "reference": "db0abb6a6983738d768b64684f82d178059b85b4",
            "shasum": "f04821a159f6f19ea6e5be8624d88f32b168e205"
        },
        "require": {
            "magento/framework": ">=100.0.0",
            "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|>=7.0.0",
            "some/core": ">=3.0.0"
        },
        "time": "2018-02-16T09:00:56+00:00",
        "type": "magento2-module"
    }
}
```

We can clearly see from this it contains both the zip and the source.

This seems to mean that when we run `composer install` it tries to install the source version first - which fails as it doesn't have read-access - then it falls back to the dist, which works.

Is this the natural behaviour of composer if there is a `source` field within the `composer.lock` ? - And if so, is it possible for satis to not generate the source object, so it automatically goes straight to the `dist` key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can exclude `source` repos from Satis output, but as an alternative, you can tell Composer to use `dist` repos by default with configuration similar to:

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

You can also specify `preferred-install` config on package by package basis, as per [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install):

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "my-organization/stable-package": "dist",
            "my-organization/*": "source",
            "partner-organization/*": "auto",
            "*": "dist"
        }
    }
}
```